# Java Array elements not getting inserted into MySQL table despite showing no error

Tags: java, mysql, xampp

This is the SQL query I am making :

```
stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql="INSERT INTO registration(phone,name,address,city,destination,date) VALUE ("+phone[i]+",'"+name[i]+"','"+address[i]+"','"+city[i]+"','"+destination[i]+"','"+date[i]+"')";
```

This is the relavant part of the program where I am  making the SQL query for context . The query seems to be correct. The program is not throwing any errors Yet the data is not getting inserted into the MySQL table

```
   case 1: {
                        System.out.println("Enter your Phone number:");
                        phone[i] = sc.nextInt();
                        sc.nextLine();

                        System.out.println("Enter your name:");
                        name[i] = sc.nextLine();


                        System.out.println("Enter your address:");
                        address[i] = sc.nextLine();

                        System.out.println("Enter your Pick up city:");
                        city[i] = sc.nextLine();


                        System.out.println("Enter your Destination:");
                        destination[i] = sc.nextLine();


                        System.out.println("Enter your Date:");
                        date[i] = sc.nextLine();
                        ++i;
                        Connection conn = null;
                        Statement stmt = null;
                        try{
                            //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
                            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                            //STEP 3: Open a connection
                            System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
                            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
                            System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

                            //STEP 4: Execute a query
                            System.out.println("Inserting records into the table...");
                            stmt = conn.createStatement();
                           String sql="INSERT INTO registration(phone,name,address,city,destination,date) VALUE ("+phone[i]+",'"+name[i]+"','"+address[i]+"','"+city[i]+"','"+destination[i]+"','"+date[i]+"')";

                        }catch(SQLException se){
                            //Handle errors for JDBC
                            se.printStackTrace();
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            //Handle errors for Class.forName
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }finally{
                            //finally block used to close resources
                           try{
                                if(stmt!=null)
                                    conn.close();
                            }catch(SQLException se){
                            }// do nothing
                            try{
                                if(conn!=null)
                                    conn.close();
                            }catch(SQLException se){
                                se.printStackTrace();
                            }//end finally try
                        }//end try
                        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                        break;
                    }
```

The program isnt throwing any errors but my MySQL is showing no new entries being inserted . Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you're constructing the string `sql` but you are not using it anywhere.

The following code is used to execute queries:

`stmt.executeUpdate(sql);`

See [Oracle - Processing SQL Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html) for more information about this.

Unrelated to your question, but [Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) is something you might want to look into aswell, since you're litterally inserting user input straight into the database. The input of the user might aswell be malicious, here is more explanation [W3Schools - SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

Comment: Did you edit your answer and posted my answer as yours?

Comment: No, I read the other question below which had a comment from agent47 that said 'Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().'. Based on that I realized I had made a mistake, and only saw your post later.

Answer (score 0):

Your `INSERT` statement should look like:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO registration (phone, name, address, city, destination, date) VALUES ('" + phone[i] + "', '" + name[i] + "', '" + address[i] + "', '" + city[i] + "', '" + destination[i] + "', '" + date[i] +"');";
```

and you should call:  
`stmt.executeUpdate(sql);`  
not `executeQuery()` because the latter is used to return rows and not insert rows

Answer (score 0):

You are only creating the statement here, there for the query will not run. I have added a code line to run the sql query after  below line, Please see the below codes. Also I saw the SQL query which you have written has small fault. Please make it correct (I have done it in below code). otherwise it will throw an exception after running the code.

```
case 1: {
                        System.out.println("Enter your Phone number:");
                        phone[i] = sc.nextInt();
                        sc.nextLine();

                        System.out.println("Enter your name:");
                        name[i] = sc.nextLine();


                        System.out.println("Enter your address:");
                        address[i] = sc.nextLine();

                        System.out.println("Enter your Pick up city:");
                        city[i] = sc.nextLine();


                        System.out.println("Enter your Destination:");
                        destination[i] = sc.nextLine();


                        System.out.println("Enter your Date:");
                        date[i] = sc.nextLine();
                        ++i;
                        Connection conn = null;
                        Statement stmt = null;
                        try{
                            //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
                            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                            //STEP 3: Open a connection
                            System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
                            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
                            System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

                            //STEP 4: Execute a query
                            System.out.println("Inserting records into the table...");
                            stmt = conn.createStatement();
                            String sql="INSERT INTO `registration`(phone,name,address,city,destination,date) VALUES('"+phone+"','"+name+"','"+address+"','"+city+"','"+destination+"','"+date+"')";
                            stmt.execureUpdate(sql); //this line will run the query
                        }catch(SQLException se){
                            //Handle errors for JDBC
                            se.printStackTrace();
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            //Handle errors for Class.forName
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }finally{
                            //finally block used to close resources
                           try{
                                if(stmt!=null)
                                    conn.close();
                            }catch(SQLException se){
                            }// do nothing
                            try{
                                if(conn!=null)
                                    conn.close();
                            }catch(SQLException se){
                                se.printStackTrace();
                            }//end finally try
                        }//end try
                        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                        break;
                    }
```

Comment: I have modified the code accordingly, Please check !